# I have a pictureBox1_MouseDown event and when i click the mouse left button it dosent work good

Tags: c#, .net

The idea is that in my program i have a button. When i click the button its drawing in the *picutreBox1* paint event the point and add it on the *pictureBox1* center + 10 pixels randomly around the center.

For example I clicked 5 times in a row and I see now 5 points.
In the *button1* click event I also add the button location X,Y to two Lists<>
List<> X have the X location of the button and Y the Y location.

Now in the mouse down event I'm calculating the nearest point to the mouse location when I click the *pictureBox1* and I also check if the lowest value distance is lower then 50 so if I click on a point ill be able to drag the point around the *pictureBox1* but only if I clicked on the point somewhere between the point center and 5 pixels from the center. That way I know which point I want to drag.

In the mouse down event I also get the index of the lowest value distance and I set a flag `movePoint` to true and then in the mouse move event I update all the time the `selectedIndex` so only the selected clicked point will move. in the mouse move event I also check if the flag `movePoint` is true and then only start the movement.

In the mouse up I update once again the `selectedIndex` with the mouse location.
And I also set the flag `movePoint` to false.

The problem is when I'm running the program add one or more points but i don't click with the mouse on a point I click on EMPTY SPACE somewhere in the *pictureBox1* and just click on it once or click and try to drag this empty space nothing happens since the flag `movePoint` is false.

** But in fact for some reason something does happen and if i click and drag empty space in the pictureBox1 area and then i click on one of the points and try to drag them the point jump to the location of where i dragged the empty space before !
I cant figure out why it happen. **

Its like I drag nothing its empty space i also don't see any point move. But then when I try to drag a point its jumping or another point is jumping to the location of where I ended dragging the empty space !!!!

This is the code of the mouse down mouse move mouse up and the paint events:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // find the index that is closest to the current mouse location
        float MinDist = float.MaxValue;

        for (int idx = 0; idx < Point_X.Count; ++idx)
        {
            float dx = Point_X[idx] - e.X;
            float dy = Point_Y[idx] - e.Y;
            float dist = (float)Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

            if (dist < MinDist)
            {
                MinDist = dist;
                selectedIndex = idx;
            }
        }

        if (MinDist < 5)
        {
            mouseMove = true;
            OriginalX = Point_X[(int)selectedIndex];
            OriginalY = Point_Y[(int)selectedIndex];
        }
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseMove == true)
    {
        Point NewPoint = e.Location;
        Point_X[(int)selectedIndex] = NewPoint.X;
        Point_Y[(int)selectedIndex] = NewPoint.Y;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point NewPoint = e.Location;
    Point_X[(int)selectedIndex] = NewPoint.X;
    Point_Y[(int)selectedIndex] = NewPoint.Y;
    mouseMove = false;
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < Point_X.Count; ++idx)
    {
        Point dPoint = new Point((int)Point_X[idx], (int)Point_Y[idx]);
        dPoint.X = dPoint.X - 5; // was - 2
        dPoint.Y = dPoint.Y - 5; // was - 2
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(dPoint, new Size(10, 10));
        g.FillEllipse(brush, rect);
    }
}
```

** I made a small video yesterday that show the problem. look from the beginning but the problem start at second 17-19 thats where i click and drag empty space in the pictureBox1 and then try to drag the points again and cant move them and if i cant move one of them the other points jump to the location of the empty space i dragged.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZr6wdF8MNA&feature=youtu.be **

Comment: In the mouse down event i check if the mouse click location was inside the point center and 5 pixels length then move the point i also find the nearest point that i want to move. But how do i add a check somewhere in the mouse down event that if i clicked in the pictureBox1 on empty space wich is length from a point or point center more then 5 pixels then it will make return; or something ? For some reason even if visualy i dont see it but when i click on empty space in the pictureBox1 and drag the empty space drag nothing it does remember this drag location ! And i dont want it to rmember.

Comment: in method pictureBox1_MouseUp. Shouldn't you do a "if (mouseMove == true)" check, because this code will still fire even if you drag empty space

Comment: TomP89 right solved it. I feel a shame and silly for not notice it. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I make silly mistakes all the timee. They are often easier to see from a different persons perspective :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)`

Should contain the logic

> if (mouseMove == true)
>               {
>   //Do stuff
>       }

That should fix the issue.